# Problem with React Router when uploading on gh pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, router

I`m having a problem when uploading project on gh-pages.This is my app :

```
    function App() {
  return (
  <>
    <Navbar/>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/Hotels" component={Home}/>
        <Route exact path="/Hotels/all" component={Hotels}/>
        <Route exact path="/Hotels/all/:hotelId"  component={Hotel}/>
        <Route exact path="/Hotels/all/:hotelId/rooms" component={Rooms}/> 
        <Route exact path ="/Hotels/all/:hotelId/rooms/:roomId" component={Room}/>
        <Route exact path ="/Hotels/all/:hotelId/rooms/:roomId/book" component={Checkout}/>
        <Route exact path ="/Hotels/successpay" component={SuccessPay}/> 
        <Route exact path ="/Hotels/errorpay" component={ErrorPay}/> 
        <Route component={Error}/> 
      </Switch>
    <Footer/>
  </>
  );
}
```

The problem is my last 3 routes do not work on gh-pages.It returns the 404 page.Everything else works fine.Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Finally found solution that works - replaced BrowserRouter with HashRouter